# Distribution inequality involving Laplace operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

> Let $u\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$. Prove that seeing as distributions,
>
> $$\triangle |u|\ge \triangle u \cdot \text{sign}(u)$$
>
> which means, $\forall \phi$ smooth and compactly supported on $\mathbb{R}^3$, $\phi \ge 0$, we have
>
> $$\int \triangle |u|(x) \phi(x) \ge \int \triangle u(x) \cdot \text{sign}(u(x))\phi (x)$$
>
> where $\text{sign}(u)$ is the sign function of $u$, equals 1 when $u(x)>0$, -1 when $u(x)<0$, 0 when $u(x)=0$.

I have tried to deal with Laplace operator and change the inequality into form $\int \text{sign}(u) (u\triangle \phi-\phi\triangle u)\ge 0$, but still don't know where to go on. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This kind of things goes under the name of "Stampacchia Calculus". See for example [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StampacchiaTheorem.html) (starting from "As noted above...", midpage). Hope this helps

Comment: That's not exactly what you need to prove. You need to show $\int |u| \Delta \phi \geq \int \Delta u \cdot \text{sign}(u) \phi $. On the right, split the integral into two regions, one where $u>0$ and one where $u\leq 0$ and proceed from there.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I don't think this is what the OP is referring to. For instance $|u|$ is not in $W^{2,p}$, so the Laplacian is distributional, and not a weak derivative.

Comment: @Jeff: It was intended more as a keyword for further research than a precise hint. Anyway, a better keyword is "Kato's inequality": https://math.stackexchange.com/q/267348/8157

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kato's Inequality with Laplacian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267348/katos-inequality-with-laplacian)

Answer (score 1):

Set $V=\{u < 0\}$ and $W = \{u > 0\}$. Then

$$\int \Delta u \cdot \text{sign}(u) \phi\, dx = \int_{W} \Delta u \phi \, dx - \int_V \Delta u \phi \, dx.$$

Apply Green's identities to get

$$\int \Delta u \cdot \text{sign}(u) \phi\, dx = \int |u| \Delta \phi \, dx + \int_{\partial W} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu_1} \phi \, dx -\int_{\partial V} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu_2} \phi \, dx$$

where $\nu_1$ is the outward normal to $W$ and $\nu_2$ is the outward normal to $V$. Since $\partial u/\partial \nu_1 \leq 0$, $\partial u/\partial \nu_2 \geq 0$, and $\phi \geq 0$ we have

$$\int \Delta u \cdot \text{sign}(u) \phi\, dx \leq \int |u| \Delta \phi \, dx.$$

Comment: Good answer. You might add some details on why one of the surface integrals coming from the Green identity vanishes

Comment: None of them vanish, there are 2 boundary terms, which are accounted for by the factor 2.

Comment: Actually there was a small error in my original proof; I assumed that $\partial \{u>0\} = \partial \{u<0\}$, which need not be true if $u$ has flat spots. Just fixed now. Basically the flat regions where $u=0$ do not contribute to either side of the inequality so they can be dropped.

Comment: Why can you integrate  by parts on the regions $V$ and $W$? The boundaries of these sets need not be $C^\infty$. Are they always sets of finite perimeter?